how to mock a third party library and assert its functions were called (or spyon) with jest?
I am working with ngrx and signalr, and writing a unit test for my ngrx effect responsible for building, starting and stopping the signalR hub.
this is my effect:
import {HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, HubConnectionState, LogLevel} from '@microsoft/signalr';
[...]

@Injectable()
export classs MyEffects{
  _hubConnection: HubConnection;
  connectSignalr$ = createEffect(()=>{}
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(connectSignalR),
      switchMap((bearerToken) => {
        this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
          withUrl('myUrl', {
            accessTokenFactory: () => bearerToken
          })
          .withAutomaticReconnect()
          .configureLogging(LogLevel.Info)
          .build();
        this._hubConnection.onClose(()=>this.store.dispatch(hubClosed()));
        return from(this._hubConnection.start()).pipe(map(()=>hubConnected()));
      })
    )
  );
}

and this is my effect.spec.ts jest test:
jest.mock('@microsoft/signalr'), ()=>{
  HubConnection: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    start: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('started')
  }),
  HubConnectionBuilder: jest.fn(()=>{
    withUrl: jest.fn.mockReturnThis(),
    withAutomaticReconnect: jest.fn.mockReturnThis(),
    configureLogging: jest.fn.mockReturnThis(),
    build: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      start: jest.fn().mockResolveValue('start'),
      onClose: jest.fn()
    })
  })
});

describe('myEffect tests', ()=>{
  [...]
  it('should build the connectionHub and start it', done => {
    action$ = of({type:'connectSignalR'});
    // const hubConnectionBuildSpy = jest.spyOn(HubConnectionBuilder, 'build'); 
    myEffects.connectSignalR$.subscribe(action => {
      expect(action).toEqual({type:'hubConnected'}); // this works and succeeds
      // expect(hubConnectionBuildSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this fails
      done();
    })
  })
})

I've tried defining the mock outside of the jest.mock argument, like this: jest.mock('@microsoft/signalr', () => SignalRMock) to maintain a reference to the jest fns, but it fails with the error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SignalRMock before initialization.
I've also tried spying on the actual library in the test as suggested in the official jest mock documentation https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials
in myEffect.spec.ts:
import {HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, HubConnectionState, LogLevel} from '@microsoft/signalr';

jest.mock('@microsoft/signalr'), ()=>{
  HubConnection: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({...}),
  ...
});
...

describe(..., ()=>{
  ...
  it('should build the connectionHub and start it', done => {
    action$ = of({type:'connectSignalR'});
    const hubConnectionBuildSpy = jest.spyOn(HubConnectionBuilder.prototype, 'build'); 
    // ☝️ this fails
    myEffects.connectSignalR$.subscribe(action => {
    expect(action).toEqual({type:'hubConnected'});
    expect(hubConnectionBuildSpy).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
    done();
  })
})

that fails with the error Property 'build' does not exist in the provided object. I've also tried creating the spy without the .prototype, like this:
const hubConnectionBuildSpy = jest.spyOn(HubConnectionBuilder, 'build');
but the error is the same.
I've browsed some other stackoverflow questions, github repos and tried reading carefully the jest documentation without any success.
I'd appreciate any idea, link or keyword I may be missing when looking for answers.
